# pods can't access to kubernets clusterIP service (10.96.0.1)

Tags: kubernetes, lxc, flannel, lxd

Recently i did install kubernetes using `kubeadm` on my old dual core AMD machine using bionic ubuntu and lxc.
This is my lxc profile which i found in web:

```
config:
  limits.cpu: "2"
  limits.memory: 2GB
  limits.memory.swap: "false"
  linux.kernel_modules: nf_conntrack_ipv4,ip_tables,ip6_tables,netlink_diag,nf_nat,overlay,br_netfilter
  raw.lxc: "lxc.apparmor.profile=unconfined\nlxc.cap.drop= \nlxc.cgroup.devices.allow=a\nlxc.mount.auto=proc:rw
    sys:rw"
  security.nesting: "true"
  security.privileged: "true"
description: LXD profile for Kubernetes
devices:
  eth0:
    name: eth0
    nictype: bridged
    parent: lxdbr0
    type: nic
  root:
    path: /
    pool: default
    type: disk
name: k8s
used_by:
 - /1.0/containers/kmaster1
 - /1.0/containers/kworker1
```

And i did run:

```
# mount --make-rshared /
# lxc config device add "kmaster1" "kmsg" unix-char source="/dev/kmsg" path="/dev/kmsg"
# lxc config device add "kworker1" "kmsg" unix-char source="/dev/kmsg" path="/dev/kmsg"
```

The `kube-proxy` couldn't run because of this error message:

```
write /sys/module/nf_conntrack/parameters/hashsize: operation not supported
```

So i did fix it by editing `kube-proxy` config and set connection tracking to zero.
After that i did deploy `flannel` as cni.
my pods can't access to default cluster IP 10.96.0.1 now, But the service is there:

```
#kubectl describe svc kubernetes
```

```
Name:              kubernetes
Namespace:         default
Labels:            component=apiserver
                   provider=kubernetes
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          <none>
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Families:       <none>
IP:                10.96.0.1
IPs:               10.96.0.1
Port:              https  443/TCP
TargetPort:        6443/TCP
Endpoints:         10.46.157.182:6443
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

May disabling connection tracking makes issue and there's using `NAT`, i don't know.
Any idea to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed that in two steps:
first I did make change the `kube-proxy` config to it's default.
Then i did write to **HOST**'s `/sys/module/nf_conntrack/parameters/hashsize` the hash size which needed by kube-proxy manually. Then delete kube-proxy pods and let it's deployment to create theme again automatically.
The main problem is `Flannel` configuration. flannel deployment doesn't looks for my cluster default ip range and set it's ip range `10.244.0.0/16`
So i did edit it's configuration and change that to my range:

```
kubectl edit cm -n kube-system kube-flannel-cfg
```

And again, delete all flannel pods and let it's deployment to create them again automatically.

Now my pod has access to kubernetes default clusterIP service.